# I'm getting 'Misssing Expression' Error. please help me finding what's wrong

Tags: oracle, replicate

```
(replicate('0',(4 - char_length(convert(varchar,extn)))) || convert(varchar,  extn)) as station_id
```

I'm getting the below error in this line:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression
```

Comment: Based on the error message, you are using oracle and not mysql. Pls tag your question correctly!

Comment: There is no replicate function in Oracle.

Comment: Nor is there a `char_length` function in Oracle. It sounds like you took some MySQL code and tried to run it in Oracle without adapting it appropriately.